# MS Project constraint changes

Tags: ms-project

I have a MS project 2010 file where I have projects with set up as "schedule from project finish date" and "fixed work" and "must finish on" constraint. now I did some importing information to manually edit. Then when I am done and then I switched from manual to auto.Then My project constraint is changing from "Must finish on" to "Finish as late as possible" which is exactly opposite what I needed.I am flexible to move around my start date or duration or assign more o less resources.Even "finish as soon as possible" or "finish no later than" constraint will work.Seems like it is switching to a default constraint "ALAP".Could anyone plaese tell me if there is a way I could set up my project with constraint "must finish on" constraint.Please Help.It will be a big help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing Right-to-Left scheduling in the project (i.e. Schedule from Project Finish Date), it follows that all tasks MUST be scheduled to finish as late as possible since it is that constraint that causes all the tasks to be scheduled "to the right".

What you may be lacking is a final milestone such as "Project Finish", which is a dependant of all prior tasks in the critical path, and upon which you must set a "Must Finish On" date equal to the project delivery date you want. You will then find that it is fixed in time and all the prior tasks are queued up behind it.

Are you sure you want to plan the project in this way? It is more usual to "front load" project planning by delivering as much as possible as soon as possible (using "As Soon As Possible" constraints)